# Use angularjs nested ng-repeat to construct complex table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble making proper table with nested ng-repeat.

What I wanted is this https://jsbin.com/razamagabo/1/edit?output

but I'm stuck at here https://plnkr.co/edit/d5voXIpzYL81sSl9BSY2?p=preview

I don't mind my markup is not table but I'm still stuck with div

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" ng-repeat="obj in data">
                {{obj.date}}
                <div ng-repeat="user in obj.users">                 
                    <br>
                    {{user.name}}
                    <br>
                    {{user.mark}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how do you want to display?

Comment: @Sajeetharan check the first link

Comment: your first link data and the plunker data are different, there is no date column

Comment: @Sajeetharan ah wrong link, now it should be ok. Thanks for notify the error.

Comment: @JessieEmerson - I don't think your going to get there with your current data model.  Currently, it is set up for the date to be the row heading and the name to be the column heading.  If you don't have control over how your data is structured you'll need to manipulate it in you angular controller

Comment: @JessieEmerson Why this particular way of displaying the info? You have a separate row for `mark`, when a clearer way would be to just display `mark` in a single row along with the user's information. I concur with @jbrown that it's not possible to achieve the result you want, with the way you have the data structured. This is what you are going to get: https://plnkr.co/edit/3EHZBCHTSskIjOS3BUI1?p=preview

Comment: @frishi I don't get you.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to display your data in the desired way, it will probably be easiest if you restructure your data in the JS before trying to render it.

It will be very complicated to try and match on the user names when they are in separate objects in the data array.

I would suggest processing your `scope.data` in the controller. (I'm assuming that you don't have much control on how you are receiving the data).

For example after you get your data...

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        date:'1-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'mark':18
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'mark':20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date:'2-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'mark':60
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'mark':55
            }
        ]
    }
]

var userData = {};
var possibleDates = [];
for (dataObj of Object.entries($scope.data)) {
    for (userObj of dataObj) {
        if ( !userData[userObj.name] ) {
            userData[userObj.name] = {};
        }
        userData[userObj.name][dataObj.date] = userObj.mark;
        if (dates.indexOf(dataObj.date) < 0) {
            dates.push(dataObj.date);
        }
    }
}

$scope.users = userData;
$scope.dates = possibleDates;
```

this will give you an object like this on your scope

```
$scope.users = {
    'james': {
        '1-1-2016': 18,
        '2-1-2016': 60
    },
    'alice': {
        '1-1-2016': 20,
        '2-1-2016': 55
    }
};

$scope.dates = ['1-1-2016', '2-1-2016'];
```

This to me seems easier to structure for your template. Though this assumes each user has an entry for each date.

```
<div>
    <div id='header-row'>
        <div id='empty-corner></div>
        <div class='date-header' ng-repeat='date in $scope.dates></div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-row' ng-repeat='{key, value} in $scope.users'>
        <div class='user-name'>{{ key }}</div>
        <div class='user-data' ng-repeat='date in $scope.dates>
            {{ value[date] }}
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as you apply `inline-block` styles to the rows/elements this should give you what you are looking for.

Though you can also think of ways to simplify your data even further. You could instead of having each user have an object where the dates are keys, you could just push the values into an array.

Comment: the user has to be an array. I can't change the data, I have no control over the API.

Comment: which is fine, you can restructure the data after you receive it so that you can render it appropriately. You will be unable to do as you hope with the current structure.

Comment: There's one way, use css?

Comment: even so, as the data is you will not be able to have one row for both instances of `james` or `alice` unless you can restructure the data so their values can be combined you will always have to different `div`s or `td`s for each occurrence.

Comment: you could use css to do a lot of things (it gets very very complicated though and not maintainable), but it's much easier to just restructure the data in your javascript. if i may ask, why would you rather use complicated css when you can easily process the data received from the api in your JS?

Comment: your loop scared me off.

Comment: I would suggest learning JS loops (as they are very useful) before trying to learn JS frameworks like Angular. Loops are a very basic part of development. And it's important to be able to use them before trying to master tools like Angular that only build on foundational JS.

Comment: what if there's extra key rather than mark? like grade, age and so on, then this structure won't work.

Comment: it will not break the code even if it is included, it just won't be rendered. If the api returns different data than you expect you can easily change the structure to account for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131827/discussion-between-jessie-emerson-and-creedjarrett).

Comment: I'm happy to discuss this over chat if you would like additional help.

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure it is not possible to display it like you want. You are trying to loop over date-users objects in `data` array but then you want to display user from inside `users` array in separate rows. With ng-repeat you can loop through rows `tr` but not through columns. First you would need to map your data array to group elements that are supposed to be visible in 1 row into 1 object in array. Currently you have them in 2 separate objects:
James mark: 18 and James mark: 60.